# How can I calculate the number of weights and bias values in a single CNN layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

Given the following image, how can I calculate the number of parameters:

[CNN Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuP9i.png)

This particular layer consists of 4x4 convolutions and 64 feature maps; how can I complete a calculation that satisfies my initial question?

[Update - Full Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGmcp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter size is contains `N * kernel_size * kernel_size` weight parameters and one for each channel so

`N * kernel_size * kernel_size* n_channels` then **N** bais parmaters so the final cacluation for this layer is  `n_params = N * kernel_size * kernel_size* n_channels + N`

---

`N : number of features`

`kernel_size : is conv2d shape (height and width)`

`n_channels : is the number of channels`

`n_params : is the total number of your parameters`

**Ex**

`n_params = 64 * (4 * 4) * 3 + 64 = 3136`